# Do Burrowed Units Block Building Construction?

Tags: starcraft-2

If I burrow a unit in a location, will the opponent be blocked from creating or landing any buildings there? If it doesn't, do my units magically move out of the way when they unburrow? (Just curious)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, it does block construction and landing. Confusingly to the other player, it will show the building in all green when they go to place or land it, but upon trying to actually land or build, will be unable to.

Comment: On confusion: that's probably a good thing. Otherwise it'd probably just be used as a free detector against zerg.

Comment: @David Liu I know the reasoning, but that doesn't really make it any less confusing when you tell your command center to land and return only to find it hovering uselessly over the landing zone instead :-P

Comment: Haha.. I was wondering if that was exploitable and if others do it(Not that I would, not a Zerg player anyway). I guess there's my answer. XD

Comment: I do this with DTs all the time!

Comment: This is extremely common in high level zerg games. The Zerg player will normally get burrow for some other unit, then send zerglings to every expansion and burrow them. This gives to benefits 1) it alerts you when your opponent tries to expand. 2) it stops the expansion and (against terran) requires a scan + moving a unit to attack the 'ling. 25 minerals for a delayed expansion + 1 wasted scan seems like a good trade to me!

Answer (score 17):

Yes, it does. My 2v2 partner and I have won games several times against unsuspecting people who never realized that we burrowed one innocuous zergling under each of their possible expansions. Been accused of hacking.

Comment: haha.. It does seem like a hack. XD

Comment: another +1 for lolz

Comment: +1 for accused hacking, by simply utilizing the features of your race.

Comment: In Starcraft 1, burrowed zerg don't block construction. Thanks for mentioning this!

Comment: @thenonhacker: In SC1 burrowed units also blocked building and landing. The only difference there was that the overlay turned red where the unit was.